# When to use double slash in HtmlAgilityPack SelectNodes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to loop through all rows in a table and select all `<p>` in a row.

```
foreach (var r in Table.SelectNodes("tr"))
{
    var Paragraphs = r.SelectNodes("//p");      
}
```

Why do I have have to use `SelectNodes("//p")` and not just `SelectNodes("p")`? If I do the latter I always get `null`.

I'm wondering why don't I use `//tr` in the foreach statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As such written `//p`, in this case, it will find `"p"` nodes located at any depth within the `HTML` tree of your `tr` element.

If you write it `/p` it will search only in the root node of the `HTML` tree of your `tr` element

**Example:**

With `//p` you will find 2 `<p>` elements, with only `/p` you will not find it and null will be return.

```html
<tr>
    <div>
       <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
       <div>
           <p></p>
       </div>
     <div>
</tr>
```

In this case, if you search by /p, the element will be found.

```html
<tr>
   <p></p>
</tr>
```

Comment: So the foreach loop works since my Table variable is a <table> HtmlNode? If it would be <body> I need to use "//tr"?

Comment: @chhenning yes but if you have multiple tables in your html page, //tr will take all tr elements from all the tables, if you search in body html node. So be careful, also this scanning of all Html tree nodes has a performance cost.  Better always select correct parent node first and after that in this node write //{HtmlElement}

Comment: Thanks, this help a lot!

Comment: What you said, is what `xpath` is supposed to do. However I think `HtmlAgilityPack` behaves a bit . I've seen that `HtmlAgilityPack` treates both of the '/p' and '//p' the same! I think It's a bug.

Comment: I was wrong, there is no but. Chrome automatically inserts `tbody` into source code, hence I thought that `htmlagilitypack` is capturing `tr` tags inside a `tbody` tag with the query of `.//table/tr`